# How to create Thumbnails for all images in the database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, jpeg, thumbnails

I guess i did not have this in mind when building this before, but now i realize i need small pictures to display so a user can choose to then view the larger image, im trying to make requests faster.

So now did this, but i don't know how to put my directory constant inside the while statement because it gets called more than once and returns "constant already defined".

I guess i have to somehow put only the path inside the while loop but i don't know how.

Here's the full code.

Well, if there's an easier way to do this i'd love that.

```
<?php
require_once '../php/db_conxi.php';
$pictures = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM imgs WHERE thumb = '' limit 20") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($row_pictures = mysqli_fetch_array($pictures)){

$uid = $row_pictures['uid'];
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "../user/".$uid."/thumbs/");
if (!file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR)){
    mkdir(UPLOAD_DIR, 0777, true);
    }       

      $filename_thumb = $row_pictures['img'];
       $photoid = $row_pictures['photoid'];
$width_thumb = 250;
$height_thumb = 250;
list($width_orig_thumb, $height_orig_thumb) = getimagesize($filename_thumb);
$ratio_orig_thumb = $width_orig_thumb/$height_orig_thumb;
if ($width_thumb/$height_thumb > $ratio_orig_thumb) {
   $width_thumb = $height_thumb*$ratio_orig_thumb;
} else {
   $height_thumb = $width_thumb/$ratio_orig_thumb;
}
$image_p_thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width_thumb, $height_thumb);
    $info_thumb = getimagesize($filename_thumb);
    if ($info_thumb['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image_thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_thumb);
    elseif ($info_thumb['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image_thumb = imagecreatefromgif($filename_thumb);
    elseif ($info_thumb['mime'] == 'image/png') $image_thumb = imagecreatefrompng($filename_thumb);

imagecopyresampled($image_p_thumb, $image_thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_thumb, $height_thumb, $width_orig_thumb, $height_orig_thumb);
$thumb = ''.UPLOAD_DIR.'/hazard_thumb_'.time().time().time().rand().rand().rand().rand().'.jpg';
$thumb_convert = imagejpeg($image_p_thumb, $thumb, 90);
//////////////Store thumb///////////
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE imgs SET thumb = '$thumb' WHERE photoid = '$photoid'") or die (mysqli_error($con));

    if ($query){
        echo 'Done with all thumbs';
        } else {
            'There was an error here';
            }
      }

?>
```

Comment: just move the define statement above the while loop.

Comment: yes but i need the user id which is inside the while loop

Comment: then make UPLOAD_DIR a variable.